# Mask an Image Using Freestyle Lines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, masking, freestyle

I'm trying to achieve a stylized ink wash or watercolor effect where the image ground remains visible. Since freestyle generates such energetic lines, I want to use them to mask my render during compositing, defining the areas where the ground will show through. So far I haven't had much success.

With the node set-up below, I'm able to apply transparent lines to my image by inverting the alpha of my freestyle render layer before combining my render layers with an "alpha over" node. Unfortunately, flipping the alpha blocks out all areas of the image that aren't freestyle lines. I'm sure I'm missing an obvious step, but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. Does anyone know what I should do?

[image: Freestyle Mask Attempt]

An ID Mask seems like it would be just about perfect, but as far as I can tell, it's not possible to create one for freestyle lines.

[Here's a simple test blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38671)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the **Set alpha** node to mask the render result with the parts where the freestyles lines are by picking the freestyle layer alpha cannel.

[image]

Notice that I also switch the **Base Thickness mode** from Center to **Inside** (see the panel on the right) to be sure to always mask parts that are actually rendered geometry and not background.

With higher values of thickness you may have some problems with the cap in the angles. I would suggest to multiply the two incoming alpha to create a mask capable of cutting them away (Multiply Math node runs the same operation of a Logic AND):

[image]

---

Now that we've "mastered" the alpha channel in a simpe way, we can **Invert** it's apha channel (check the **RGB** box to invert its values as if it was an image from the colr channel) to get a stencil look to the image:

[image]

You can make the jiggled edges by using one (or a comobo of more) of the several modifiers available, for example a **Noise** for the Thinkness parameter:

[image]

---

If you need to use the freestyle layer color to mask the rendered object, you'll need to set it of a different color from total black, or you won't be able to get its information without accessing the alpha channel anyway.

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting effect Carlo, but not quite what I'm trying to achieve. in fact, I think it's just about the opposite.

I want to preserve the transparency of the background, but cut the areas covered by freestyle lines *out* of the normal render. I suppose mask was the wrong term to use, so that's my fault. I want to uses the freestyle lines similarly to bridges in a stencil, as well as adding some irregularity to the contours of my rendered form.

Comment: Don't worry, it's just a matter of inverting the colors (as you were correctly doing). I've edited the answer in this sense.